# Rollback the installed files during at the time of uninstall cancelation

Tags: c#

how to roll back the installed files when clicking cancel button during uninstallation?

Roll back means restore the installed files.

Comment: Pretty much every "installer" library out there that creates a `.msi` file does this out of the box. Just pick one.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [wix-toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/). It has all features for full fledged windows installer

Comment: can you please share the wix xml configuration?